# saving HTML in an action

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a `viewSuccess.php` template that renders some HTML

What I'm looking to do, is to try and capture this HTML and save it as a PDF.

I have an action called `executeSavePage` which currently saves a PDF.

I could use something like `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` in the view template, but how would I then send this to my savePage action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`get_partial()`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/PartialHelper#method_get_partial) function (part of the Partial helper)

```
$html = $this->get_partial('view',array('item1' => 'value1'));
```

`$html` will contain the result of the partial rendering